# Oplog Timstamp to ISODATE conversion in PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a timestamp from oplog as `'ts': Timestamp(1413438497, 1)`
Hoe can i convert this into ISODATE.
It is working from Mongo Shell

```
x = Timestamp(1413438497, 1)
isodate = new Date(x.t*1000)
```

But it is not working with Pymongo. It is showing an error `'Timestamp' object has no attribute 't'`.
Here is my code

```
import pymongo
import datetime
from pymongo import Connection
con = Connection()
db=con['local']
oplog= db['oplog.rs']
for doc in oplog.find({'ns':'hospital.patients'})   :
     x =  new Date(doc['ts'].t*1000)
     print x
```

Comment: show us your python code.

Comment: @avi: i've included my code also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have the timestamp in python datetime object using `pymongo.timestamp.Timestamp.as_datetime()` (documentation [link](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/timestamp.html#pymongo.timestamp.Timestamp.as_datetime))

```
...
...
print doc['ts'].as_datetime() #this is a python datetime object
...
...
```

You can convert to ISO format easily(documentation [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat)):

```
datetime_object.isoformat()
```